# Undefined reference for libpq functions

Tags: postgresql, linker, makefile, g++

I have two projects, one is a library that uses libpq headers and the executable, that links to my library and to libpq, but no matter how I put in the makefile, it just doesn't link the libpq and aways return me an undefined reference error. It links my lib ok.

```
g++  -o MYAPP  main.o -L../Libs -lpq -lMYLIB
```

both libpq.a and libmylib.a are inside the Libs directory.
I used nm to check the functions and they are there, I changed the -lpq to -lpq_ and the compiler complains about the missing lib, so it is finding and theorically, linking, but can't find the references?

this is really bugging me out, what could it be?

(my english is not that good, sorry)

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I quickly checked some of the postgre headers I have flying around and they seem to not wrap themselves up in `extern "C"` when compiled with a C++ compiler. Could it be possible that your problem is resolved by enclosing the include statements for postgre's headers within an `extern "C" { ... }` block?

Edit.
I think the problem is this: `libpq.a and libmylib.a`. I overlooked this in your original post at first, sorry for the noise. When you give `-lpq` to gcc it tries to link dynamically. *Unless* you give a library directory with -L *and* there live only static versions of the libraries. Static libraries cannot document which other libraries they need to pull in. Also, with static libraries, specification order is important. Libraries that depend on other libraries need to be listed before them. By installing via apt-get you installed shared libraries that properly document what else they need to link (check `ldd /usr/lib/libpq.so`). So, in your previous attempt, you probably just needed to reverse `-lpq` with `-lMYLIB` and list the other libraries that libpq needs.

Comment: I added     extern "C" { #include "libpq-fe.h" } and didn't work

Comment: AFAIK, linking order doesn't matter with dynamic libraries, but in case you haven't tried yet, you could reverse `-lpq` and `-lMYLIB`.

Comment: I did that, then it gives me way more udnefined errors, but for other stuff inside the libpq, like kerberus and this was bugging me out. But now it is working... what I did was to remove my Libs directory that I created for linking purposes, then installed libpq through apt-get and let the g++ link with this new lib, then it didn't give me anymore errors. I guess it linked with other libraries as well? This is kinda news to me. If anyone bare to explain...

Comment: I updated my answer in that respect. Also, regarding your original unresolved symbols: They probably occured because MYLIB uses symbols from libpq that MYAPP did not need to pull in. Reversing `-lpq` and `-lMYLIB` resolved that issue, but then kerberos et al. were missing. GCC/GNU ld links from left to right. With static libraries, only symbols that are *currently* unresolved get resolved. Then ld moves on to the next library. That's why order is important.